# Connecting ethernet shield to computer

Tags: arduino-uno, ethernet

What configuration settings do I need to change on my computer to use the ethernet shield mounted on my Arduino UNO as I don't want to connect the ethernet shield to the router?

Comment: That depends entirely on the settings you have on the Arduino. Also note a special cross-over cable may be required.

Comment: What ethernet library do you use one the Arduino? And what is your network configuration? And what is the type of your _Ethernet Shield_?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to connect it to the router? It's not directly accessible from the internet by doing so.

Comment: And what operating system are you using? (Windows/Linux/MacOS)

Answer (score 1):

First off you need a basic understanding of TCP/IP networking. One you have that you need to:

1. Allocate yourself a new subnet - one that's not your normal local network (say 192.168.1.0/24)
2. Assign an IP in that subnet to your Arduino (say 192.168.1.1)
3. Assign a different IP in that subnet to your PC (say 192.168.1.2)
4. Configure your Arduino's sketch with it's IP address and netmask
5. Configure the PC's Ethernet interface with it's IP address and netmask
6. Connect the two together with a suitable cable.  If the PC's Ethernet port doesn't have auto-direction sensing you will require a special cross-over cable where TX+/TX- and RX+/RX- are swapped over.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the easy way 
This always works for me :D

1. Connect the shield to the Arduino and plug in the cables to the
   PC(RJ45/Ethernet).
2. Go to network communication center.
3. Go to change adapter settings.
4. Select Ethernet(Arduino) and wireless(Wifi) /(internet source) and
   right click.
5. Click bridge connections.
6. Wait for a few seconds.
7. **Enjoy**.